# After the most recent Ubuntu update I cannot login

Tags: updates, login-screen, bug-reporting

I have searched through other questions but none of the answers or comments have worked.
I havent been able ti update mt computer for a while so I did it all at once and many changes were made. I reboot it then made some more updates. After I updated PlayOnLinux and rebooted I wasnt able to login. I guess it might not be the last ubuntu update, but that was the biggest thing I did during the session.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is to try to recover your password. You can do so by following the information given at the following page.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LostPassword

You may want to print this out before rebooting your system, just in case you forget a step.

Good luck

Comment: I know my password though. It just goes black and then returns to the login screen like nothing happened.

Comment: Ok, then maybe the upgrade/update you did has caused some problems. If you created a separate partition for /home than this shouldn't be an issue, you won't lose any data. If you didn't make a separate /home partition then you will need to run a backup. Also you can hitting Ctrl+Alt+F2 at login to be sent to a console. Now you can login and try running  'sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade". Maybe some more updates will fix the issue. If that still doesn't work for you, from the console you can look at your logs and see if you can find out what is causing this issue.